# How to Override .signup() on Django-Allauth Form

Tags: python, django, forms, registration, django-allauth

I am trying to override `.signup()` on a form that inherits from `django-allauth`'s `SignupForm`, but it does not seem to be working. My main goal is to save an instance of the `UserProfile` model at the same time as saving the `User` model.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
class MySignupForm(SignupForm):
    """ This form only used for django-allauth package (called in Settings.py) """
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'First name'}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Last name'}))
    dob = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'date', 'min': '1940-01-01', 'max': '2030-01-01'}))  # HTML5 Widget... works?

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        login_url = reverse_lazy('account_login')

        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Div('first_name', css_class='col-md-6'),
            Div('last_name', css_class='col-md-6'),
            Div('dob', css_class='col-md-12', style='clear: both'),
            Div('username', css_class='col-md-12', style='clear: both'),
            Div('email', css_class='col-md-12'),
            Div('password1', css_class='col-md-12', style='clear: both'),
            Div('password2', css_class='col-md-12'),
            HTML('<div class="col-md-12"><br></div>'),

            FormActions(
                Submit('submit', 'Register', css_class='btn btn-primary', style='display:block;clear:both;margin: 0 0 15px 15px;float:left'),
                HTML('<a href="{0}" class="btn btn-default" style="margin: 0 15px 15px 0;float:right;display:inline">Sign In</a>'.format(login_url))
            )
        )

    def signup(self, request, user):
        print(form.cleaned_data['dob'])
        return user
```

As you can see, I am trying to `print()` the `dob`, but when I try signing up, nothing shows up in my terminal! Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

you need this in your settings.py

```
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'yourproject.yourapp.forms.SignupForm'
```

**EDIT**:

you can just use the post_save signal to create userprofile instance

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

@receiver(post_save, sender=User, weak=False, dispatch_uid='models.create_userprofile')
def create_userprofile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

Comment: I actually did that already - the custom fields show in my registration form, but the `print()` statement isn't printing, which means that it is not being executed on signup.

Comment: @Hybrid i am not sure if you already tried that but you can listen to post_save signal. see my edit above

Comment: there is also `pre_social_login` signal. --> `from allauth.socialaccount.signals import pre_social_login`

Comment: The problem with this approach is that I will loose access to the `dob` field, which I need to save in the `UserProfile` model, NOT the `User` model